# HTML entity inside of jQuery html()

Tags: jquery, html, html-entities

I have a hidden div and a link to toggle the div's visibility. The link contains text/html that needs to also toggle ('hide'/'show'). Here is my function:

```
jQuery('#toggle_filter_link').click(function() {
    jQuery('#searchfilter_wrap').slideToggle("slow");
    jQuery(this).html(jQuery(this).text() == 'Hide &uarr;' ? 'Show &darr;' : 'Hide &uarr;');
});
```

This function works as intended until I add the arrows to the HTML (`&uarr;` and `&darr;`), at which point it toggles to "Hide ↑" the first time, and then remains stuck.

Here a **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8dvNW/)**.

I assume that I need to escape the HTML Entities somehow, but considering that the first switch works I am a bit confused. It's probably something obvious that I'm missing though. :-)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try adding \ before the ;s

Comment: Adding \ before the ; did not work unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're comparing **text** to **html**

Change `jQuery(this).text()` to `jQuery(this).html()`.

Note that you might still have issues due to the way that browsers normalise HTML and you would probably be better off testing some other condition.

```
jQuery('#toggle_filter_link').click(function() {
    jQuery('#searchfilter_wrap').slideToggle("slow");
    var $this = jQuery(this);
    if ($this.hasClass('show')) {
        $this.removeClass('show');
        $this.html('Hide &uarr;');
    } else {
        $this.addClass('show');
        $this.html('Show &darr;');
    }
});
```

… or just testing for something that isn't going to be normalised:

```
jQuery('#toggle_filter_link').click(function() {
    jQuery('#searchfilter_wrap').slideToggle("slow");
    jQuery(this).html(jQuery(this).text().indexOf('Hide') > -1 ? 'Show ↓' : 'Hide ↑');
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Changing to .html() did not work, probably because of the way HTML gets normalized as you mentioned... so I am now testing for indexOf('Hide') which works like a charm.